# Ansible nmcli module - requirement issue

Tags: debian, ansible, networkmanager

I am trying to use the Ansible nmcli module on a Debian 9 target.
I am getting the following error:

> This module requires NetworkManager glib API

The Ansible documentation says that I need **NetworkManager-glib**.
On Centos and RHEL this package is very easy to find. But on Debian, I don't find it. I have install all Network-manager packets without success... Even libnm-glib4 package.

Answer (score 3):

Install `libnm-glib-dev` and try again.

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore in ubuntu 20.04.  But libnm-dev does.

Answer (score 0):

If look a the code, you can see that:

```
import  from gi.repository import NetworkManager, NMClient
```

So, you can conclude that the package python-gi is required. (Debian/Ubuntu).

```
apt-get install python-gi
```